# How to help a person in SO?

Tags: support, comments

If I have 1 reputation, I don't have enough reputation to comment on someone's post, but I want to help him/her. What should I do in this situation?

The only way to interact is through posting an answer, but if I do so everybody flags it.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a hypothetical question for the benefit of others, you seem to have 10k+ rep on SO?

Comment: Some people leave contact info in their profile so you can contact them directly if you want it so much.

Comment: Thanks I gonna give this like to all who not able to help because of them reputation

Answer (score 8):

You have to wait until you have enough reputation (answer a question, ask a good question yourself). Let other people extract the needed information from the OP.

According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), you should never ask more information using an answer. It will indeed get deleted.

Comment: +1 because that's the way SO is supposed to work, but let me tell you, it was *extremely frustrating* for me when I started and saw all the questions I could answer if only I could get a bit more clarification. It took what seemed like ages to encounter the few questions answerable directly, answer them fast enough (SO is murderously quick at times), and gain enough rep for the comment privilege.

Comment: I think we all went there one time, and now we have lots of rep. :)